# 4D (3D and color) level sets

Tags: r, plot, python-3.6, 4d

How can I create 4D (3D plus color) plot that will have multiple 3D surfaces with different colors?

I have only 3 vectors of integers (x, y, z) and a function with 3 arguments (x, y, z) that returns integer = color. Function accepts integers, not whole vectors and returns single integer.

I'm OK with either R or python 3 solution.

Surfaces would be my level sets.

In every solution in Internet I have found, colors are bound by one of the dimensions (usually z) and I do not want this. I want my color to be separate information.

Is it possible if vectors have different lengths?

Comment: Is z a function of x and y ? Otherwise I don't understand which surfaces you're talking about.

Comment: No. Z is not a function of X and Y. Surface would be an image of one level set.

Comment: So you want to plot a point with color f(x,y,z) at coordinates (x,y,z), if I understand.

Comment: Yes. That's right.